# A confusing error of executing commands in foreach in Csh

Tags: foreach, csh

The program is very simple:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
foreach path ( fileA.txt fileB.txt )
    wc -l $path
    grep "test" $path
end
```

However, the output is:

```
fileA.txt/wc: Not a directory.
fileA.txt/grep: Not a directory.
fileB.txt/wc: Not a directory.
fileB.txt/grep: Not a directory.
```

So what's wrong with the code and what's the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You should never use **path** as a generic variable name in C-Shell since it contains the current search directories for the shell to find the command programs.

This will work much better than your code:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
foreach mypath ( fileA.txt fileB.txt )
    wc -l $mypath
    grep "test" $mypath
end
```